# Can you take a catapult on the boat?

Tags: kingdom-new-lands

I can make a catapult for either direction despite there only being enemies coming from the West (on the first island, anyway).

I know you can use the boat to take a number of archers and builders (and Knights, after some googling) on to the next location, but can it be used to transport a catapult as well?  The machine still seems to stop at my furthest wall on that side but I'm wondering if I clear all the trees or something if it will continue to the dock so I can take it with me.  I won't bother spending the coin if it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible to take the catapult with you. By default, you will take 4 archers and 3 builders (assuming you have the numbers). It is also possible to take 2 knights and their 4 archers each. You will also take the mount you are riding, and any hermits on your back, as well as any coin in your purse.